# Issue while updating files and subfolders from source to destination folder using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a script that duplicates all files and subfolders from the source folder to the newly created destination folder. It works fine when it creates a new destination folder. However, the issue arises when I need to update files and subfolders in an already existing destination folder. For example, If source folder has this structure:

```
Template Folder (Source Folder)
 - SubFolder 1
 *File 1
 *File 2
 - Sub Folder 2
 * File 3
 * File 4
```

And an already existing destination folder has this structure:

```
 Name X (Destination folder)
- SubFolder 1
*File 1
- Sub Folder 2
* File 3
* File 4
```

When I run the following script:

```
function updateFolderContents(sourceFolder, destinationFolder) {
  var sourceFiles = getFilesInFolder(sourceFolder);
  var destinationFiles = getFilesInFolder(destinationFolder);

  // Remove files from destination that don't exist in source
  for (var i = 0; i < destinationFiles.length; i++) {
    if (!fileExists(destinationFiles[i], sourceFiles)) {
      console.log("Deleted File: " + destinationFiles[i].getName())
      destinationFiles[i].setTrashed(true);
    }
  }

  // Check and add new files
  for (var i = 0; i < sourceFiles.length; i++) {
    if (!fileExists(sourceFiles[i], destinationFiles)) {
      console.log("Added File: " + sourceFiles[i].getName())
      destinationFolder.createFile(sourceFiles[i]);
    }
  }

  var sourceSubfolders = sourceFolder.getFolders();
  var destinationSubfolders = getSubfoldersInFolder(destinationFolder);

  // Remove subfolders from destination that don't exist in source
  for (var i = 0; i < destinationSubfolders.length; i++) {
    if (!folderExists(destinationSubfolders[i], sourceSubfolders)) {
      console.log("Deleted folder: " + destinationSubfolders[i].getName())
      destinationSubfolders[i].setTrashed(true);
    }
  }

  // Check and add new subfolders
  while (sourceSubfolders.hasNext()) {
    var sourceSubfolder = sourceSubfolders.next();
    var existingDestinationSubfolder = getFolderById(sourceSubfolder.getId(), destinationSubfolders);
    if (!existingDestinationSubfolder) {
      var newSubfolder = destinationFolder.createFolder(sourceSubfolder.getName());
      console.log("Added folder: " + sourceSubfolder.getName())
      updateFolderContents(sourceSubfolder, newSubfolder);
    } else {
      updateFolderContents(sourceSubfolder, existingDestinationSubfolder);
    }
  }
}

function getFolderById(folderId, folderArray) {
  for (var i = 0; i < folderArray.length; i++) {
    if (folderId === folderArray[i].getId()) {
      return folderArray[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
}


function getFilesInFolder(folder) {
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var fileArray = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    fileArray.push(files.next());
  }
  return fileArray;
}

function getSubfoldersInFolder(folder) {
  var subfolders = folder.getFolders();
  var subfolderArray = [];
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    subfolderArray.push(subfolders.next());
  }
  return subfolderArray;
}

function fileExists(file, fileList) {
  for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
    if (file.getName() === fileList[i].getName()) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function folderExists(folder, folderList) {
  for (var i = 0; i < folderList.length; i++) {
    if (folder.getName() === folderList[i].getName()) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

The current workflow is like this:

```
 Deleted SubFolder 1
 Deleted SubFolder 2
 Added File 1 in SubFolder 1
 Added File 2 in SubFolder 1
 Added File 3 in SubFolder 2
 Added File 4 in SubFolder 2
```

The issue is, that instead of just adding the `File 2` in `SubFolder 1` and keeping all the files the same, it deletes all subfolders and then starts adding files in them again. I need your guidance to resolve this issue. Please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Can you please provide how you put the input folder so we don't have to change your existing code to replicate your work.

Comment: I personally find that doing this sort of thing is much more successful with recursion rather than simple looping.

Comment: @Twilight, what do you mean by input folder? Both source and destination folders can be accessed by `getFolderByID()` and passed in this function. The folder structure of both folders is also mentioned in the question

Comment: your function folderExists() does not loop properly since the folder list you are using is `var sourceSubfolders = sourceFolder.getFolders();`, it worked when I changed it to `var sourceSubfolders = getSubfoldersInFolder(sourceFolder);` however changing it to this affects other parts of the code using the sourceSubfolders. You may want to restructure your code.

Comment: About `updating files and subfolders from source to destination folder using Google Apps Script` in your actual situation, I have 4 questions. 1. Do you want to synchronize the source folder and the destination folder using a Google Apps Script? 2. If after a file "A" is copied from the source folder to the destination folder, the file "A" is updated in the source folder, what do you want to do about the file "A" in the destination folder?

Comment: 3. If a file in the source folder is deleted, what do you want to do about the destination folder? 4. Do you want to keep the file IDs of the files in the destination folder even when the files are copied?

Comment: 3. I want to sync both folders, whatever the file/subfolder is deleted from the source folder it should mirror the same changes in the destination folder. Currently, if I delete any file from a subfolder from the source folder, then this script deletes that whole subfolder from the destination folder.

Comment: 4. I want to keep files instead of file IDs in the destination folder.
1. Yes I want to synchronize it using the apps script, the above script does that, but it deletes all the subfolders (the only issue with the above script) from the destination folder before syncing it with source folder

Comment: 2. Answer to your `the file "A" is updated in the source folder`, file will not be updated, it would only be added or deleted in source folder or subfolder of source folder.